# Alternative to xxd for QNX

Tags: command-line, qnx

I was just introduced to `xxd` today. See [link](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xxd1.html). I am very familiar with the QNX `hd` and `od`commands, both of which will take input and create a hex dump (or octal dump if you like). See [hd](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/utilities/h/hd.html) and [od](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/utilities/o/od.html).

What I am looking for is the `xxd -r` capability to go backwards from a hexdump to a binary file, but apparently QNX doesn't have that, or I'm not reading the description appropriately. Can someone point me in the right direction?

This is regarding QNX Neutrino 6.4.1 or newer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to compile xxd for QNX instead of trying to find an alternative: ftp://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/pub/utilities/etc/xxd-1.10.tar.gz

The source is small (less than 1000 lines) and it has defines for windows and amiga so I expect it's fairly portable.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the link to the source. That was easy. Though QNX choked on the makefile, a simple `qcc xdd.c` and I was in business. I feel silly for not thinking of this myself.